# Criação de objetos (factory) javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

Olá, Estou tendo a tentar criar dois objetos do tipo **pessoa** usando `Factory` e na primeira tentativa eu criar o primeiro elemento e a segunda tentativa em vez de criar o segundo elemento cria um novo elemento, mas com as mesmas características que o primeiro elemento

`Classe Pessoa`, que será uma `super classe`

```
function Pessoa(id, nome) {
  this.id = id;
  this.nome = nome;
}
```

`Classe Aluno` **extends** `Pessoa`

```
function Aluno(id, nome) {
  Pessoa.call(this, id, nome);
}
```

`Classe Professor` **extends** `Pessoa`

```
function Professor(id, nome) {
  Pessoa.call(this, id, nome);
}
```

utilizando a função de `factory` para **criar aluno** e **professor**

```
function Factory() {
    var idAluno = 0;
    var idProfessor = 0;

  this.criarPessoa = function(tipo, nome) {
    var pessoa = new Pessoa();
    switch (tipo) {
      case "1":
        pessoa = new Aluno(idAluno++, nome);
        break;
      case "2":
        pessoa = new Professor(idProfessor++, nome);
        break;
    }
    return pessoa;
  }
}
```

`Classe Escola` com uma **lista de pessoas**[`alunos e professores`]

```
function Escola(id) {
  this.pessoas = [];
  this.factory = new Factory();
  this.pessoaCriada = null;

  this.criarProfessorOuAluno = function(tipo,nome) {

    if (tipo!== null) {
      this.pessoaCriada = this.factory.criarPessoa(tipo,nome);

      this.pessoas.push(this.pessoaCriada);

      console.log("\nID: "+this.pessoas[this.pessoaCriada.id].id+
      "\nNome: "+this.pessoas[this.pessoaCriada.id].nome);
    } else {
      console.log("não pode ser vazio");
    }
  }
}
```

teste no cmd, node app.js

```
var escola = new Escola(1);
escola.criarProfessorOuAluno("1","Jonh"); // 
escola.criarProfessorOuAluno("1","Bob"); // 
escola.criarProfessorOuAluno("1","Jerry"); // 
escola.criarProfessorOuAluno("2","Tom"); // 
escola.criarProfessorOuAluno("2","Peter"); //
```

e obtive esse resultado

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

e não aparece os **nomes dos professores** **Tom** e **Peter**, ou se for apenas para **um tipo de pessoa funciona tudo bem** e se quiser **criar outro tipo de pessoa, retorna o valor das pessoas que já se encontram criadas**

Comment: da um `console.log(this.pessoas)` esta lá dois índices, do Aluno e Professor, agora  e só você percorrer eles corretamente para mostrar as informações.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O teu código está correto e podes verificar isso se fizeres `console.log(escola.pessoas);` que vai dar

```
[{
    "id": 0,
    "nome": "Jonh"
}, {
    "id": 1,
    "nome": "Bob"
}, {
    "id": 2,
    "nome": "Jerry"
}, {
    "id": 0,
    "nome": "Tom"
}, {
    "id": 1,
    "nome": "Peter"
}]
```

O que não está correto é como estás a verificar com a consola os dados que estás a criar. Quando usas

```
console.log(
    "\nID: " + this.pessoas[this.pessoaCriada.id].id +
    "\nNome: " + this.pessoas[this.pessoaCriada.id].nome
);
```

estás a usar o `ID` do tipo de pessoa. Ou seja em vêz de estares a verificar a pessoa 1, 2, 3 (independentemente de ser Aluno ou Professor) estás a verificar o índice  em `this.pessoas` lendo o `id` interno que está relacionado com quantos desse tipo já existem.

Ora no caso de ser o primeiro Professor registado vai ser `0` e vais estar a buscar o nome de `this.pessoas[0].nome` e não `this.pessoaCriada.nome` que é o que procuras. Se criares depois o primeiro Aluno vai dar de novo `0` e vais receber outra vez o mesmo valor. Estás portanto a apontar a lanterna para o sitio errado.

Creio que queres usar

```
var ultimo = this.pessoas.length - 1;
console.log(
    "\nID: " + this.pessoas[ultimo].id +
    " Nome: " + this.pessoas[ultimo].nome
);
```

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0c72r1uq/

Comment: obrigado, deu certo, funciona perfeitamente. valeu

Comment: @DSanches ótimo, de nada.

Comment: as vezes pequenas instruções o programa não funciona como pretendido mas ainda bem que havia solução